# Powershell send f5 key to edge

Tags: powershell, key, send

Im trying to create a script that refresh edge:

```
start microsoft-edge:https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=eu
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('Microsoft Edge') 

while ($true)
{
Sleep 15
$wshell.SendKeys('{f5}') 
}
```

Problem for this that it sends F5 to which windows im at for example if im in notepad it will press f5 it will create timestamp, i want it to send only to edge, is there any way around it?

Comment: I haven't done something specifically like this but I think you may not be attacking the problem in the best way. You press the f5 key to refresh the page when in the browser, but your class likely has a method for refreshing the page. Try inspecting the object to see if you can find something like that. Also, if wshell is sending keystrokes to the wrong application, your AppActivate line may not be doing what you think it is. Can you focus on that application specifically with another command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code snippet could do the job. You need to tell *which* window should be activated, e.g. a s follows:

```
$medge = Start-Process -PassThru -FilePath microsoft-edge:https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=eu
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell

Start-Sleep -Seconds 15                  ### increase time for slow connection
while ( $wshell.AppActivate($medge.Id) ) ### activate the desired window
{
    $wshell.SendKeys('{f5}')             ### send keys only if successfully activated
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 15
}
```

Above code snippet (derived from the one in question) refreshes *microsoft-edge* every 15 seconds.

Timing is important:

- grant *microsoft-edge* enough time to run and establish connection (see `Start-Sleep` *before* `AppActivate`), and
- send keys immediately after the window is activated.

Answer (score 0):

This worked partially for me, the change that we made was to have it look like this:

```
$medge = Start-Process -PassThru -FilePath microsoft-edge:https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=eu
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell

Start-Sleep -Seconds 15                  ### increase time for slow connection
while ( $true ) ### activate the desired window
{
    $wshell.AppActivate($medge.Id)
    $wshell.SendKeys('{f5}')             ### send keys only if successfully activated
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 15
}
```

Hope it helps for anyone out there!